# Error al escribir en base de datos mysql desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

el codigo php me da por resultado que no puede guardar los datos en la base de datos... alguna idea de porque?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost" , "root" , "");

if (!$con) 
{
    echo 'No conecta al servidor';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'estrella'))
{
    echo 'No conecta a base de datos';
}
//numero de cedula Funcion*("codigo html")//
$Cnombre1 = $_POST['nombre1'];
$Ncedula = $_POST['ncedula'];
$Nlocal = $_POST['nlocal'];
$Cnombre2 = $_POST['nombre2'];
$Capellido1 = $_POST['apellido1'];
$Nnit = $_POST['nit'];
$Capellido2 = $_POST['apellido2'];
$Nccomercio = $_POST['nccomercio'];
$Cdireccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$Ctelefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$Cvalor = $_POST['cvalor'];
$Ccuotas = $_POST['ccuotas'];
$Cfechain = $_POST['fechain'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO contrato (Nombre1, Ncedula, Nlocal, Nombre2, Apellido1, Nnit, Apellido2, Ncamara, Direccion, Telefono, Ccontrato, Vcuotas, Vfechainicio) VALUES ('$Cnombre1', '$Ncedula', '$Nlocal', '$Cnombre2', '$Capellido1', '$Nnit', '$Capellido2', '$Nccomercio', '$Cdireccion', '$Ctelefono', '$Cvalor', '$Ccuotas', '$Cfechain')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
{
    echo 'No Guardado';
}
```

?>

Comment: Simple, tu query da error. Usa `mysqli_error` para ver la razón. Aparte tu insert es muy vulnerable a inyecciones sql. Deberías usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: dentro de tu if agrega esto `echo mysqli_error($con);` una vez hecho esto muestranos que error te da

Comment: Eso hice y halle el error, aparentemente tenia una variable mal declarada... gracias